# Function operator= must be a member function

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, friend, non-static

I have a function prototype inside a public class access specifier.
This is the prototype:

```
friend void operator=(String &s,char *str);
```

The String is the class where it's prototyped. As you can see it's a friend function. By keeping it this way it gives me this error:

```
operator =' must be a non-static member // Error: operator= must be a member function
```

And when I remove the friend property it gives me this error:

```
error C2804: binary 'operator =' has too many parameters
```

What's wrong with this prototype? There's no call at operator= function currently, so there shouldn't be any error even without the function definition.

Comment: `String& operator=(char *str);`

Comment: While that solves the error, why would you ever have operator=() return void??

Comment: @dans3itz: My brain was switched to "lazy mode" :) You're right, I edited the comment

Comment: Even better, if you have an implicit conversion constructor for `const char *` (taking `char *` is really unexpected to the caller) defined, `String &operator=(String s)` and copy-swap it.

Answer (score 2):

If it's part of the String class, then it's an assignment of soemthing to `this`, so it only takes one argument.

Comment: It's part of my String class. I'm trying to do a version of mine. I've tried to do your way, but it gave me an error of memory allocation so I've dumped the idea.

Comment: @RobertEagle: When you have errors, you should probably fix them.

Comment: @RobertEagle: You probably messed up with your `char` pointers. By "dumping the idea" all you've done is masked the underlying fault, meanwhile restricting yourself to an _incorrect_ and _illegal_ approach that does not compile.

Comment: @RobertEagle I would urge you to figure out what was causing the "error of memory allocation" and fix it.  Memory management is an important part of learning how to write C++, and it pays to get good with it early on.